# How to define the crystal frequency when building nodemcu firmware?

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I am trying to build for a board that has a 40MHz crystal. I am building on my own Linux machine. I do not see a config option to change this. Is there a place to set the crystal frequency? Or is it only set at time of flashing the firmware?

Answer (score 0):

The boot ROM does the smart stuff.  You may need to set it for flashing.  ESPTOOL and the other flashers allow this. But once booted you have the [node.setcpufreq(speed)](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/modules/node/#nodesetcpufreq) function and the corresponding `getcpufreq()` function.

Comment: I was looking for the crystal frequency. This is for CPU frequency. I didn't see a way to set or change crystal frequency from node module. I assume it is only set at time of flash. But I think arduino IDE requires it to be set during build time. So I didn't know if nodemcu build required it set somewhere. I cannot find anywhere to set it. Thanks

Comment: I think that you'll need a soldering iron and a new crystal to change the crystal frequency.  Not something for StackOverflow ;-)